# Logistic regression with only 1 dummy variable

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b','b', 'b','b','c','c','c'],
                   'val':[1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1]})

print(df)
id group  val
0   1     a    1
1   2     a    0
2   3     a    1
3   4     b    0
4   5     b    1
5   6     b    1
6   7     b    0
7   8     c    0
8   9     c    1
9  10     c    1
```

I want to see if **ANY** of the `group`, has a significant effect on val.

So what I do a logistic regression as follows:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

dummy_variables = pd.get_dummies(df['group'], drop_first=False)

logit_model = sm.Logit(df['val'], dummy_variables)
result = logit_model.fit()

print(result.summary())
```

Notice the `drop_first=False` and I also do not add a constant in the model, due to multicollinearity.

At my real data (not the dummy example) i get a `p-value < 0.05` for `dummy_a` and a `p-value > 0.05` for `dummy_b` and `dummy_c`.

Is it right to say that `a` has a signifficant effect on `val` ?

Comment: what you are asking is not really a programming quesiton - the p-value is used to potentially reject a null-hypothesis, commonly a statistical significance level of 0.05 is used. when p < 0.05 you usually say the result is "statistically significant"

Comment: yes, indeed. it is not a programming question. It is a question about interpretation. My question is if I can say that only one category of a dummy variable is significant and the rest are not

Comment: so you should post it on stats.stackexchange and not on stackoverflow - voted to close this. you can have a look at this question for some inspiration: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401991/what-to-do-with-categorical-variables-that-are-partially-significant